# Playing Card Class - is this right?

Tags: java, optimization, classes, playing-cards

*The Art and Science of Java*, a course book that uses the ACM library, has an exercise that reads like this:

> Implement a new class called Card that includes the following entries:
>
> • Named constants for the four suits (CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES)
>   and the four ranks that are traditionally represented in words (ACE,
>   JACK, QUEEN, KING). The values of the rank constants should be 1, 11,
>   12, and 13, respectively.
>
> • A constructor that takes a rank and a suit and returns a Card with
>   those values. • Accessor methods getRank and getSuit to retrieve the
>   rank and suit components of a card.
>
> • An implementation of the toString method that returns the complete
>   name of the card.

Now, this question is a little hard to understand, but nevertheless I've done a class that I think answers this:

```
/** Ficheiro: Carta.java
* 
* Classe que vai representar os diferentes valores e naipes de uma carta de um baralho normal
* de 52 cartas. Exercício para construir uma classe completa juntamente com construtores,
* gets de Valores e Naipes e de método toString.  */

public class Carta {

// Constantes do Naipe (Rank) das Cartas
public static final String AS = "Ás";
public static final String REI = "Rei";
public static final String DAMA = "Dama";
public static final String VALETE = "Valete";

// Constantes do Valor Facial (Suit) das Cartas
public static final String COPAS = "Copas";
public static final String PAUS = "Paus";
public static final String OUROS = "Ouros";
public static final String ESPADAS = "Espadas";

/**
* Cria uma nova carta de um baralho regular de 52 cartas.
* @param valor O valor facial da carta (ex. Ás, Rei, 10...)
* @param naipe O naipe da carta
*/  

public Carta (int valor, int naipe) {
    valorCarta = valor;
    numNaipe = naipe;
}

/**
 * Obtém o valor facial da carta (existem 13 valores faciais)
 * @return O valor facial da carta em String
 */

public String getValorCarta() {
    switch (valorCarta) {
    case 1: return AS;
    case 11: return REI;
    case 12: return DAMA;
    case 13: return VALETE;
    default: return "" + valorCarta;
    }
}

/**
 * Obtém o naipe da carta (existem 4 naipes)
 * @return O naipe da carta em String
 */

public String getNaipeCarta () {
    switch (numNaipe) {
    case 1: return COPAS;
    case 2: return PAUS;
    case 3: return OUROS;
    case 4: return ESPADAS;
    default: return ("Naipe Inválido");
    }
}

/**
 * Cria uma representação em String da Carta (Valor e Naipe)
 * @return Representação em String da Carta (Valor e Naipe)
 */

public String toString () {
    return getValorCarta() + " de " + getNaipeCarta(); 
}

// variáveis de instância que registam o Valor e o Naipe da Carta em integers.
private int valorCarta;
private int numNaipe;
}
```

Sorry about the commentaries.  I speak Portuguese and I've written the commentaries in that language. I hope the code is easy enough to understand.

I want to know if I have written well the class, according to specifications, especially the Public Constants and the Get Methods.

I am not sure if they wanted me to make the constants `int` types instead of `String`s. Also I didn't assign any parameters to the Get Methods, so they will only give me the rank or suit of a new Card Object. I am not sure if they wanted me to attribute an int param to these methods.

As a sidenote, I wrote a short program that demonstrates this class in action, in choosing and displaying a random card (note that the run method is the main method in `acm` libraries):

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;

public class testeCarta extends ConsoleProgram{

// Escolhe uma carta aleatóriade um baralho de 52 cartas e imprime no ecrã
public void run () {
    println ("Este programa vai seleccionar uma carta aleatória");
    Carta cartaAleat = new Carta (rGen.nextInt(1,13),rGen.nextInt(1,4));
    println (cartaAleat);
}

// variável de instància que permite a utilização de gerador de números aleatórios
public RandomGenerator rGen = RandomGenerator.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: I would think that you did not do it right. I believe they are hinting at using a enum. Because your method accepts 2 integers you could put a suit into a rank and a rank into a suit and Java wouldn't complain. If you used a enum though your types would be checked and that problem is reduced.

Comment: @RobertSnyder The Book where I did this exercise still hasn't made any mention of Enums so I'm pretty sure they aren't meant to be used in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Enums

Java enums have been around for a long time, so it's really a waste **not** to be using them at this point.

*However*, I understand that this may simply be an *exercise*, to test and build your understanding of Java, one step at a time.  If that is the case, (or maybe if the exercises are given in a specific order, and you haven't yet progressed to the Chapter on `enums`) then maybe you are intended to avoid them.  I'll work on that assumption (no enums).

### Representation

> Named constants for the four suits (CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES)
>   and the four ranks that are traditionally represented in words (ACE,
>   JACK, QUEEN, KING).

A *named constant* simply means that in code, your Java can refer to constant values with variable names that are meaningful.  It does **not** mean that those constants must be `Strings`, and usually, they should not be.  If you have:

```
public class Carta {

    public static final int REI = 11;
```

then, this code is using a *named constant*:

```
int rank = REI;
```

while this code is not:

```
int rank = 11;
```

> The values of the rank constants should be 1, 11, 12, and 13, respectively.

This clearly is requesting an implementation where the constants are integer types, not `String` objects:

```
public static final int AS = 1;      // Ace
public static final int VALETE = 11; // Jack
public static final int DAMA = 12;   // Queen
public static final int REI = 13;    // King
```

(you'll have to double check my values .. I don't speak Portuguese, and I think I recognize the word *Rei* and *Dama*, but not the others)

These constants are in addition to the other cards, ranked `2` through `10`.

### Specification Terminology

> ... that are traditionally represented in words

This language may be confusing, I understand.  When they say "words", they're not asking for `String` constants.  They are referring to the fact that, outside of JACK/QUEEN/KING/ACE, the other cards are 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 ... which are **numbers**.

### Comments

You have some comments here (again, with my limited understanding of Portuguese), that I believe are backwards:

```
// Constantes do Naipe (Rank) das Cartas
public static final String AS = "Ás";

// Constantes do Valor Facial (Suit) das Cartas
public static final String COPAS = "Copas";
```

`As` (or Ace) is not a `Naipe`, it is a `Valor` (value, or rank).  Even if the **code** is correct, it's important in software development to make the comments correct, too.

### toString()

Finally, concerning the specification for `toString()`, I believe that your existing code satisfies the requirement.  But, remember, the constants really should be implemented as integers, not `String` constants.  So, if you rewrite the class to represent values as integers, you'll then need a new method to convert integer values to `Strings`.

A `HashMap<Integer,String>` would probably work for that purpose.  If you haven't gotten to using *generics* yet, even an array of strings (`String[]`) could be used to map `int` values to `String`, as long as you keep track of the 0 index, or use the 0 index element as an `Invalid` value.

Comment: +1 Good job with the Portuguese. It's not easy. I say this because I do speak it myself.

Comment: I once worked in an office cube with an Australian guy who talked to his Brazilian wife on the phone all the time :)

Comment: @Nate Thank you for you help in understanding the exercise. I see now that it was int all along that they wanted, so I'll atribute those to my Switch Cases (like switch (numNaipe) { case COPAS: return "Copas";) and will work from there. Your Portuguese is really admirable... yes I had that comment in Portuguese wrong - it was late and I was getting very sleepy :) - I will also correct it ofc! Thank you very much for your input, I learned something new today!